# Instana agent one liner installation error on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04, monitoring, instana

I tried installing instana agent using docker command and it works but I need it be installed using one liner command and when tried it gives error as below:

```
curl -o setup_agent.sh https://setup.instana.io/agent && sudo chmod 700 ./setup_agent.sh && sudo ./setup_agent.sh -a <myinstanakeyreplaced> -t dynamic -l us -y -s
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12664  100 12664    0     0  11439      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 11439
Setting up Instana agent for GNU/Linux
Setting up Instana APT repository
Importing Instana GPG key
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
Updating apt metadata ...
W: GPG error: https://packages.instana.io/agent/deb generic Release: Detached signature file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.instana.io_agent_deb_dists_generic_Release.gpg' is in unsupported binary format
E: The repository 'https://packages.instana.io/agent/deb generic Release' is not signed.
```

I tried on private wifi (with no proxy) but still the same. Can anyone help on this error?

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the notification, we're working on that. It seems that it only happens on distribution versions, we do not yet support. What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Hi, Sorry.. i forgot to mention the details..

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=disco
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 19.04"
VERSION="19.04 (Disco Dingo)"

Comment: Thanks, as I thought, the release is not yet supported. Engineering is working on support and will make it available as soon as possible. I'll keep you posted if you like.

Comment: Ok should be fixed by now 

Answer (score 1):

the Instana repository has been upgraded to support Disco Dingo as well.